# class path resource [db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist; when running jar file

Tags: spring, jar, liquibase

I want to build an executable jar file, but I'm having trouble running it in cmd. When running application in IntelliJ, then it starts fine. I know that basically the exact question has been around, but its answer (`spring.liquibase.change-log` instead of just `liquibase.change-log`) doesn't seem to apply in my case.

When running jar file, then last part of the error looks like this (I hope this is the part that matters the most):

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: Error parsing classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
        at liquibase.parser.core.yaml.YamlChangeLogParser.parse(YamlChangeLogParser.java:83)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.getDatabaseChangeLog(Liquibase.java:216)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:189)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:178)
        at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:368)
        at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:316)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
        ... 61 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:202)
        at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase$SpringResourceOpener.getResourcesAsStream(SpringLiquibase.java:601)
        at liquibase.util.StreamUtil.singleInputStream(StreamUtil.java:186)
        at liquibase.parser.core.yaml.YamlChangeLogParser.parse(YamlChangeLogParser.java:26)
        ... 68 common frames omitted
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=p******
spring.datasource.password=t****
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
```

db.changelog-master.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                      http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">
    <include  file="db/changelog/db.changelog_tables.xml"/>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Just like the person with the same question I don't understand why it is searching for file `[db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml]` when I have specified the property : `spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml` in the application.properties file. Or have I misunderstood smt totally, cause running application in IntelliJ and running jar file are two totally different things?

I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Is your `db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml` located into `${porject.basedir}/src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml`  ?

Comment: No, it isn't, because I don't have .yaml file. But db.changelog-master.xml is indeed located in ${porject.basedir}/src/main/resources/db/changelog.
I understood that I don'n need both, db.changelog-master.xml and db.changelog-master.yaml file.

Comment: You don't need both `db/changelog/db.changelog_tables.xml` and `db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml`... If `db.changelog-master.yaml` carry a reference to `db.changelog_tables.xml` you need both.

Comment: Well, I didn't mention `db/changelog/db.changelog_tables.xml`.
I wrote, that I understood that I don't need both `db.changelog-master.xml` and `db.changelog-master.yaml` file. I only have `db.changelog-master.xml` (located in `${porject.basedir}/src/main/resources/db/changelog`), which carries a reference to `db.changelog_tables.xml` (which is also located in `${porject.basedir}/src/main/resources/db/changelog`). I hope I made it more clear now.

Comment: Yes yes `yaml` or `xml` is up to you.

Comment: I guess then I'm back in square one. When it's up to me weather I use `yaml` or `xml` (fyi: I use the latter), then why is `[db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml]` searched at all?

Comment: Because it's in the defaults settings of `liquibase`.